# TableView's viewWillAppear() called but data is not refreshed

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Sometimes tiny looking problem is ignored to handle in the last but you never know that will become nightmare for you, happening with me.

Thanks in advance, problem my app's settings page contains tableView and every setting element is one of the view. One of the setting item (row) offers show expands a few list of items in another listTableView. After making a selection in listTableView when i come back to my settings tableView using navigationItem.leftButton (Back), selected item value overlaps the previous item's value, in the sense [tableView reloadData] in viewWillAppear works fine but tableView rows are not fresh drawn. It doesn't refresh the cell's UI.

Note that if settingTableView has any subview like UIButton etc it has the latest value, i can use that as workaround but the only problem is when is select this row again Selection has old value that overlaps new value on selecting the row.

I will appreciate any suggestion or sample code using will be great help.

Thanks a ton
Amit Singh

Comment: What's in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and `viewWillAppear` method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[tableView reloadData];` in your `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: i am using reloadData in viewWillAppear only that is the reason if data is placed in a UIbutton gets refreshed...

Answer (score 0):

or use `[tableView reloadData];` in `viewDidAppear` method

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is perhaps due to portion of cell that is reusable and the one that is not reused. Check out the code you are writing inside the block of

```
if(cell==nil){}
```

components you have created inside block will not get recreated and others might be recreating causing the overlapping on the cell.

Comment: i am using in ...   if(cell == nil) {
  cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
 }

Comment: and getCellContentView: contains  > - (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {
 
 UITableViewCell *cell;
  UIViewController *tempController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:(NSString *)@"NibName" bundle:(NSBundle *)nil];
  cell = (UITableViewCell *)tempController.view; 
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
 
 return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use [self.tableView reloadData]; rather than [tableView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear method.